# Basis for the left invariant subspace

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ given by :
$$
G=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} / x^{2}+y^{2}=1 \text { et } z>0\right\}
$$
Show that the vector fields $$
X:=-y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \text { et } Y=z \frac{\partial}{\partial z}
$$
Form a basis for the left inavriant vector fields subspace.

---

Let $g=(g_1,g_2,g_3), x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in G$ and $L_g$ is defined by : $L_gx=(g_1x_1,g_2x_2,g_3x_3)$.

We know that $$T_xL_g=dL_g x=\begin{pmatrix} g_1&0&0\\0&g_2&0
\\ 0&0&g_3   \end{pmatrix}$$
so $X$ is said to be left invariant vector field if $(L_g)_* X=X$  which is equivalent to show that : $$T_xL_g X_x=X_{gx} \quad \text{ for all } x,g \in G$$
so $T_x L_g X_x=\begin{pmatrix} g_1&0&0\\0&g_2&0
\\ 0&0&g_3   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -x_2\\x_1\\0  \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} -g_1x_2\\ g_2x_1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $X_{gx}=\begin{pmatrix} -g_ 2x_2 \\ g_1x_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ !!!

For $Z$ : $T_xLg Z_x= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\ g_3x_3  \end{pmatrix}=Z_{gx}$

I don't know where's the problem ? If we let $X=-x\partial_x+y\partial_y$ I think it works !
Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you're using the wrong group structure. The group action of $\mathbb{C}^* \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ should not act as a scaling $(g_1,g_2) \cdot (x_1,x_2) = (g_1 x_1, g_2 x_2)$, but by complex multiplication, so
$$(g_1,g_2) \cdot (x_1,x_2) = (g_1 x_1 - g_2 x_2, g_1 x_2 + g_2 x_1).$$
This will make some rotations appear, and should fix your problem.

Note in particular that with this structure, your subspace $G$ actually turns into a subgroup: The circle is invariant under rotation, but if you take the component-wise scaling from your solution, that won't be a subgroup.